Excel vba- how to disable entire right-click contextual menu
I have an Excel workbook with worksheets that I am able to protect and hide, and unprotect and show as needed. I've hidden menus, scroll bars, etc.
That part works.
What is not working is trying to hide any and all (preferable all at once) any contextual menu by right-clicking. Specifically R-Clicking on tabs and inside of cells doesn't appear to be working.
I have seen the following code (also I am not sure what I am supposed passing to the sub()
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("Sorry Right Click is Disabled for this Workbook")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   Cancel = True
End Sub

Any recommendations?
My Workbook is too large to attach, sorry. I can email it to someone if they want to see it at work.

The first subroutine belongs in the workbook code module. It's an event handler, you don't need to invoke it or pass anything to it.

Side note. There shouldn't be any parentheses with the MsgBox call.

If you add the first Sub to the workbook code module then you won't need the second one in each worksheet code module.

none of these are working. When I right click on the sheet tab the context menu still exists, also when I click into a cell it appears
